# JPA CriteriaBuilder - sort by the number of associated entities in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have two entities Customer and Order in a one-to-many relation. 
For each customer I need to count the number of associated orders and sort the results by this number. 
In a native postgres query it looks like this:

```
select cust.id, count(order.id) from customers cust
left outer join orders order
on cust.id = order.customer_id
where .... conditions ...
group by cust.id
order by count desc;
```

But I must do this using CriteriaBuilder because this query is part of a larger piece of code that uses CriteriaBuilder to put in additional conditions. In Hibernate I would have probably used Projections, but I can't find anything similar in JPA.

Any help in composing the query using CriteraBuilder would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at a good tutorial. I personally suggest [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Supposing that the entity Customer has a `OneToMany` property like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerId")
private Collection<Order> orders;
```

You can use the following query:

```
EntityManager em;  // to be built or injected
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Customer> customer = cq.from(Customer.class);
CollectionJoin<Customer, Order> orders = customer.join(Customer_.orders, JoinType.LEFT);
cq.select(cb.tuple(customer, cb.count(orders)));
cq.where(... add some predicates here ...);
cq.groupBy(customer.get(Customer_.id));
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.count(orders)));
List<Tuple> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
for (Tuple t : result) {
    Customer c = (Customer) t.get(0);
    Long cnt = (Long) t.get(1);
    System.out.println("Customer " + c.getName() + " has " + cnt + " orders");
}
```

The above approach uses [Metamodel](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/). If you don't like it, you can replace `Customer_.orders` with `"orders"` and `Customer_.id` with `"id"`.

If the `OneToMany` property is of another type, replace `CollectionJoin` with the collection of the proper type (`ListJoin`, `SetJoin`, `MapJoin`).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work in my case - the reason being that the code into which I'm trying to integrate mine is so contructed that it uses     `findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)` from `SimpleJpaRepository` - passing in a `Pageable` object that also must contain the sort by column. If I do not specify the column to sort by in the `PageRequest(int page, int size, Sort sort)` but do so via the CriteariaBuilder as you advised above - it simply assumes that the sort is null and overrides whatever order I specify in the CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: I can't understand, can you clarify? However this seems a completely different question. I suggest to open a new one and mark this answer if it answered to the original question, which it seems the case indeed.

Comment: This happens in `SimpleJpaRepository`, line 417: `query.orderBy(toOrders(pageable.getSort(), root, builder));`. I'm examining the spring-data sources to find a way to make it work with both Pageable and not override the order that I specify in the CriteriaBuilder. If you could advice me further, I'd really appreciate it. Although I know you've helped me a lot already. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, haven't seen your reply. Yes, you're right it's probably worth opening another question. Still I'll clarify: What the code does is: `customerRepository.findAll(new CustomerSearchSpecification(searchFilter), pageable);`. Pageable looks like this: `PageRequest(1, 10, new Order(Direction.DESC, Customer_.name.getName()); ` For my case - I can't use a Metamodel column - so I'm passing null for Order - in which case it doesn't matter what I specify in the CriteriaBuilder, it simply overrides it adding no order to the select.

Comment: Sort.Direction and PageRequest are spring classes, of which I am not expert. Please open a new question about this. However it looks suspicious the use of Direction inside the Order constructor: is Direction a property to be persisted? I would say no.

Comment: Yes, those are spring classes, I'll have to open a seperate question about this. The Order you are referring to is not the entity, it is org.springframework.data.domain.Order - which is used to specify the column to order by and direction.

Comment: I had a very similar case and this answer helped me much, thank you.
I'd like to ask if there's a way to write this as query, in JPQL? Because I tried and failed.

Answer (score 2):

Use this inside the specification

```
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.count(orders)));
```

Also send `PageRequest(1, 10, Sort.unsorted())`. This is how I did it.
If you are passing the Sort value as unsorted and then override criteria query with your own logic of sorting on your joined entity